# Isolating/removing Characters from string using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby on rails

I have

```
article.id = 509969989168Q000475601
```

I would like the output to be

```
article.id = 68Q000475601
```

basically want to get rid of all before it gets to 68Q

the numbers in front of the 68Q can be various length
is there a way to remove up to "68Q"

it will always be 68Q and Q is always the only Letter
is there a way to say remove all characters from 2 digits before "Q"

Comment: Your sample code is invalid. Do you mean that the value being assigned is a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
article.id[/68Q.*/]
```

Which will return everything from `68Q` to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the split method:

```
'68Q' + article.id.split('68Q')[1]
```

This splits the string into an array based on the delimiter you give it, then takes the second element of that array. For what it's worth though, @theTinMan's solution is far more elegant.

Comment: How does return what the OP requested?

Comment: @theTinMan woops, my mistake - I gave him the reverse. I'll fix it. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

```
article.id.match(/68Q.+\z/)[0]
```